# Codeigniter list_fields

Tags: codeigniter

I have the ff code :

```
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT fname AS firstname, lname AS lastname FROM table");
$query_fields = $query->list_fields();
```

Now the value of `$query_fields` will be :

```
array(2) {
  [0]=> "firstname",
  [1]=> "lastname"
}
```

Is there a way or solution that i can get the `fname` and `lname`?
My prefer output would be:

```
array(2) {
  ['fname']=> "firstname",
  ['lname']=> "lastname"
}
```

Any solution or comment?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
 $query = $this->db->query("SELECT fname AS firstname, lname AS lastname FROM table");
```

to

```
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT fname , lname FROM table");
```

You will have fname and lname instead of firstname and lastname.

You can iterate over the result set to make your own array.

Comment: Thank you for the answer yes i know that but assuming that the given query has alias. How would I do that?

Comment: @reignsly you can't get back the actual columns names because the result set return lastname an firstname so you wont be able to revert back the aliases... why do you need that by the way?

Comment: Yes, I thought so im just hoping there is a solution. Im creating a dynamic CRUD where developers will just throw mysql query and the CRUD will fetch and display the result in a table. The list of fields will be the header column names. If there is a way better but if none then it will need a second parameter of field names. Im trying to eliminate the second parameter.